# When plotting a correlation matrix with pairs(), how to display long column names in many lines?

Tags: r

After drawing the correlation matrix in R, I try to read it in binary form in an external program.
However, each column name is too long, so in the correlation matrix drawn in `pairs()`, parts of both sides of the column names are cut off.

If the column name is this long, is there a way to make these column names appear in multiple lines?
And can we increase the fontsize of the column names to increase readability?

This is the sample code.
In this case, for example, I want the column

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

to look like

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

in two lines.

[image: result image (correlation matrix)]

```
a <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
b <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
c <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
d <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
e <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
f <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
g <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
h <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10
i <- runif(100, 0, 30) + rnorm(100, 5, 1) + 10

df <- data.frame(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = a,
                 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB = b,
                 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC = c,
                 DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD = d,
                 EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE = e,
                 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = f,
                 GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG = g,
                 HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH = h,
                 IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII = i)

pairs(df,
      lower.panel = NULL,
      upper.panel = function(x, y){
        points(x,y,pch=20)
        r <- round(cor(x, y, use = "complete.obs"), digits=2)
        txt <- paste0("R = ", r)
        usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
        text(1, 0.95, txt, col="red", pos=2, cex=1.0)
      },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by using the function `stringi::stri_extract_all` on a long label to break it down into chunks of at most ten characters

```
longlabel <- "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
small_chunks <- stringi::stri_extract_all(longlabel, 
                                          regex = ".{1,10}")[[1]]
```

After that, you can use `paste` to get

```
betterlabel <- paste(small_chunks, collapse = "\n")
```

And test that it works:

```
hist(rnorm(100), main = betterlabel)
```

[image: Histograaaaaaaaaaaaam]

On your example, you would need to wrap all that into an `sapply` to wrap the column names of `df`, like so:

```
colnames(df) <- sapply(stringi::stri_extract_all(colnames(df), regex = ".{1,10}"), paste, collapse = "\n")
```

to obtain the desired result:

[image: Pair scatterplot]